# Two Dimensional Array of Structs in C - how to declare and use

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, struct, malloc

I've been trying to get a very simple idea to work in C but I can't even get the syntax down.
 
This program would take in some inputs from the command line and use them to decide what size to make a 2 dimensional array of structs.

Then, in a for-loop type situation, I'd like to be able to change a specific unsigned char based on user input. So first I build a 2D array of structs, each struct containing an array of unsigned chars as well as a name, and then I am able to write to these.

The command line arguments are three strings. `First one is number of rows, second one is number of columns, third one is size of unsigned char array within each struct.`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
    typedef struct {
    unsigned char* Data;
    char* name;
    } myStruct;

    myStruct* myArr[][];

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
       int y = atoi(argv[0]);
       int x = atoi(argv[1]);
       int z = atoi(argv[2]);
       myStruct* myArr[x][y];

      for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
     {
         for(int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
           myArr[i][j]=(myStruct*) malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
           myArr[i][j].Data=(unsigned char*)  malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*z);  
           myArr[i][j].name = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*64);
        }
     }

     //part II - change some entry of myArr based on input from user
     //assume input has been taken in correctly
     int h = 5;//5th row in myArr
     int k = 7; // 7th column in myArr
     int p = 9; //9th unsigned char in myArr[h][k].Data
     unsigned char u = 241;//value to be written
     char* newName = "bob";
     myArr[h][k].Data[p]=u;
     myArr[h][k].name=newName;

     return 0;
    }
```

This code does not work. In fact, it does not compile. Could someone help me? I am simply trying to understand pointers as a way to transition from java to C. This is the kind of thing I'd be able to do very very easily in Java and I want to be able to do it in C as well. I've heard that a 2 D array has to be declared outside main so it is global in scope, because the stack is limited in size and a 2D array of structs just might fill it. Can someone explain that, too? And how I would declare a 2D array whose size is determined at run time?

I intend to use C and only C for this, too. So please don't provide me with C++ syntax tips. Thanks.

Comment: note : `argv[0]` is program name. delete `myStruct* myArr[][];`

Comment: I thought it is simply the first string in the array of strings constructed from the command line arguments. Am I wrong? What do you mean by program name?

Comment: e.g. `prog.exe 7 8 9` : argv[0] : "prog.exe", argv[1] : "7", ...

Comment: `myStruct* myArr[x][y];` then `myArr[i][j]->Data` , `myStruct myArr[x][y];` then `myArr[i][j].Data`

Comment: `myArr[h][k].name=newName;` --> `strcpy(myArr[h][k].name,newName);`

Comment: Oh so this fixes the "deprecated conversion from string constant to char*" warning the compiler throws at me, yes?

Comment: `char* newName = "bob";` : `"bob"` is string constant. It is not a special problem if you do not want to change the contents.

Comment: Also h is 6th row and k 8th in your sample (indexes start at 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 myArr[h][k].Data[p]=u;
 myArr[h][k].name=newName;
```

should be

```
 myArr[h][k]->Data[p]=u;
 myArr[h][k]->name=newName;
```

because they are pointers. The same error occurs in your loops.

```
myStruct* myArr[][];
```

This line is invalid and meaningless, because you re-define it in the main().

If you want to allocate a dynamical array, you can use:

```
myStruct **myArr = malloc(x * y * sizeof(**myArr));
```

Comment: The compiler still doesn't like "myStruct* myArr[][];" which you can find outside the main method in the code above. What gives?

Comment: @mufasa56 because it's invalid. You have to specify the dimensions of your array.

Comment: So these large data structures can definitely be declared so they end up in the stack? I was under the impression this would give an error.

Comment: Also, if I allocate dynamically, would each value still be accessed using [row][column]? Or is the structure now a 1 dimensional list?

Comment: Yes, you can. I sighltly edit the last line, although both should work.